# Jasper server reportUnitUri cause 404 error

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I use jasper reports rest v2 api, in http:///jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions send post request with the following body

```html
<reportExecutionRequest>    
   <reportUnitUri>/root/Reports/samples/Department</reportUnitUri>     
   <async>true</async>   
   <freshData>false</freshData>    
   <saveDataSnapshot>false</saveDataSnapshot>  
   <outputFormat>html</outputFormat>    
   <interactive>true</interactive>  
   <ignorePagination>false</ignorePagination>   
   <pages>1-5</pages>   
   <parameters>    
     <reportParameter name="name">      
       <value>name 1</value>            
       <value>name 2</value>       
     </reportParameter>       
     <reportParameter name="mark1">    
        <value>200</value>    
        <value>453</value>  
     </reportParameter>    
   </parameters>
</reportExecutionRequest>
```

reports Resource /root/Reports/samples/Department not found. i tried various combinations in `ResourceUnitUri` like (Reports/Reports/samples/Depatments, /samples/Department). But none seems to work. Everything returns 404 code. What is the correct value on reportUnitUri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReportUnitUri = /reports/<folder name>/<Resource ID>`. To get Resource ID select report and click edit button. you get